# Параметризированный запрос к SQL Visual Studio на C++

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, visual-c++

Необходимо написать параметризированный запрос к SQL Visual Studio на C++.

```
SQLCHAR sqlString[] = "insert into Foto (Kartina) values(?)";   
retcode = SQLPrepare(hstmt, sqlString , SQL_NTS);
```

Функция SQLPrepare возвращает -2. В чем ошибка или сам метод неправильный?

Answer (score 1):

Цифра -2 ни о чем не говорит. Согласно [описанию](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710926(v=vs.85).aspx) функция возвращает ряд значений: `SQL_SUCCESS`, `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO`... и если код возврата `SQL_ERROR` или `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO`, то детальная информация об состоянии получается с помощью вызова функции `SQLGetDiagRec`.